# Why doesn't this simple code example change my MUI theme to 'dark' mode?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new to React and MUI, but this seems like a pretty simple example.  I am trying to display 'hello world' in dark mode palette using MUI 5.1.0. I created this simple app using 'npx create-react-app myHelloWorld' on Windows 10 & Chrome.

```
import React from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

function App() {
  const darkTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      mode: 'dark'
    },
  });

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
      Hello World
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I run this, everything shows up in black on white (the 'light' palette, which is the default).  I would like the reverse.  Any ideas on what could be going wrong?  It seems so basic...I must be missing a big picture item.

Comment: Just a clarification - I continued on my way using the default 'light' theme and when I added other components it started to work properly.  Problem solved.  Interestingly, I originally had <Typography>Hello World</Typography> which also didn't work.  I had to add other components (like AppBar).

Answer (score 0):

you need to use MUI tags like this :

```
 import {Box, Typography} from "@mui/material";

       return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
           <Box>
                <Typography variant="h6" component="h6"> Your information was successfully registered. </Typography>
           </Box>
        </ThemeProvider>
      );
```