# MUI - dark theme doesn't change anything

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new to MUI, but all was pretty easy to understand beside changing to dark theme.
I opened documentation of MUI at page where there are examples with dark theme. I copied the first example and it didn't work to me. [Why doesn't this simple code example change my MUI theme to 'dark' mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70049113/why-doesnt-this-simple-code-example-change-my-mui-theme-to-dark-mode) from here I understood that I need to add more components, but I didn't really understand what does it mean. If I don't add DOM tree it doesn't work? Why the background doesn't change?!

```js
import React from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

function App() {
  const darkTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      mode: 'dark'
    },
  });

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
      Hello World
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shoul add `<CssBaseline />`

```
import React from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

function App() {
  const darkTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      mode: 'dark'
    },
  });

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      Hello World
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Any docs or description for that?

Comment: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-css-baseline/ @LevShapiro